# How to do multi value count aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to do a "multi value count" aggregation?
It would work the same way as the regular value count: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html

But would be used to count multiple fields.

For example we have a mapping:

```
"properties" : {
        "lastName" : { "type" : "string" },
        "firstName" : { "type" : "string" },
        "age" : { "type" : "string" }
}
```

And the following 4 docs:

```
{"lastName":"Smith"}
{"lastName":"Jacobson", "firstName":"Scott"}
{"lastName":"Bush", "age": 68}
{"lastName":"Obama", "firstName":"Barack", "age":53}
```

I would like to count the number of documents with either an age OR a first name.
In my case the aggregation would return 3.

Any idea ? I try a little bit using the script function:

```
"aggregation_name" : {
  "value_count" : {
    "script" : "doc['age'].value + doc['firstName'].value"
  }
}
```

but it did't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [filter aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation) and [Exists filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) -

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "CountSpec": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "age"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "firstName"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I managed to achieve what I wanted with: `"count_name" : {
          "value_count" : {
            "script" : "if(doc.containsKey('age') || doc.containsKey('firstName')) { 1 }"
          }
        } `   Any idea what would be best : the filter aggregation or the value aggregation with a script ?

Comment: Certainly filter approach. Scripts are CPU intensive and filters are natively build. More importantly scripts have filter cache which means that the execution would be much faster once its cached